# Unchecking a checkbox and modifying value of sum

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am trying to design a menu. If you check a box, then sum get added up and if you uncheck it, the sum is reduced. I face trouble in reducing the sum while unchecking the box and also the value of sum is not globally changed. Please help me out.

```
<head>
    <script>
        var sum=0;
        function a(sum,num) {
            sum=sum+num;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=sum;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Dal" id="dal" onclick=a(sum,10)>Dal<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Rice"  id="rice" onclick=a(sum,20)>Rice<br>
    <h1> Total Price is : </h1>
    <p id="demo"> 0 </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the markup, add a value and a class, and remove the inline JS

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Dal" id="dal" value="10" class="myClass">Dal
<input type="checkbox" name="Rice" id="rice" value="20" class="myClass">Rice

<h1> Total Price is : </h1><p id="demo">0</p>
```

Then do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass'),
        total  = document.getElementById('demo');

    for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].onchange = function() {
            var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
            total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add
        }
    }
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qRn5D/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var sum = 0;
function a(id, num) {
    if(id.checked == true){
        sum += num;
        id.onclick = function() { a(id, num)};
    }
    else {
        sum -= num;
        id.onclick = function() { a(id, num)};
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=sum;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95pvc/2/

Comment: But how to know whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked

Comment: if(document.getElementById(id).checked == true){ //do something }

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function a (elem, num) {
    var k = (elem.checked) ? 1 : -1;
    sum = sum + k * num;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Dal" id="dal" onclick="a(this, 10);">Dal<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Rice"  id="rice" onclick="a(this, 20);">Rice<br>
```

Comment: Because you've `sum` as an argument, this shadows the global `sum`. When you manipulate `sum` in `a`, it's a local variable, i.e. an argument of `a`, and the global `sum` is invisible to `a`. Notice, that you don't need to pass global `sum` to function at all, since it's global, function can access it anyway. Though this my answer maybe is the shortest way to get your code to work, I'd suggest you to use the approach in adeneo's or David's answer in your production code.

Answer (score 0):

My own take would involve removing the event-handling from the HTML (unobtrusive JavaScript) for easier maintenance in future, using `data-*` attributes to contain the price and using a class-name to identify the relevant ingredients, to give the following HTML:

```
<input class="ingredients" type="checkbox" name="Dal" data-price="10" id="dal" />Dal
<input class="ingredients" type="checkbox" name="Rice" data-price="20" id="rice" />Rice
 <h1> Total Price is : </h1>

<p id="demo">0</p>
```

Which leads to the following JavaScript:

```
var ingredients = document.getElementsByClassName('ingredients');

function price() {
    var result = document.getElementById('demo'),
        curPrice = 0,
        ingredients = document.getElementsByClassName('ingredients');
    for (var i = 0, len = ingredients.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (ingredients[i].checked) {
            curPrice += parseFloat(ingredients[i].getAttribute('data-price'));
        }
    }
    result.firstChild.nodeValue = curPrice;
}

for (var i = 0, len = ingredients.length; i < len; i++) {
    ingredients[i].addEventListener('change', price);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EH4hS/3/).

To avoid having to iterate through the relevant checkboxes, it might be better to wrap those `input` elements in a `form`, and then bind the event-handling to that form:

```
var ingredients = document.getElementsByClassName('ingredients');

function price() {
    var result = document.getElementById('demo'),
        curPrice = 0,
        ingredients = document.getElementsByClassName('ingredients');
    for (var i = 0, len = ingredients.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (ingredients[i].checked) {
            curPrice += parseFloat(ingredients[i].getAttribute('data-price'));
        }
    }
    result.firstChild.nodeValue = curPrice;
}

document.getElementById('formID').addEventListener('change', price);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EH4hS/2/).

References:

- [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute).
- [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).